# Asp.net mvc4, knockout js, knockout ViewModel loads for all views?

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc4 and knockoutjs and need help understanding how the views work.

1. I have a _Layout.vbhtml in Shared folder and it's the "master" page for all pages in the project.
2. I have AccountController, HomeController and GrowerController
3. I have Grower folder for the GrowerController in the Views folder. Index is the default view as usual.
4. In Views/Grower/Index, I have a knoockout ViewModel that retrieves data from the server.
5. **Now, when I go to other views like Home/Index, I see in Firebug's console that, it's making those calls to get data from the server even though I am not on the view where I created the knockout ViewModel.**

I am very confused. Does it happen because I use _layout.vbhtml for all pages? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
***_Layout.vbhtml***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>@ViewData("Title")</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
       <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        @* Javascrips files *@
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <!-- Custom stylesheet overriding styles -->
        @If Request.QueryString("pr") = "dow" or ViewData("pr") = "dow" Then
         @<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CustomDow.css")" />
        Else
         @<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Custom.css")" />
        End If
     </head>
     <body>
       <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
            @If IsSectionDefined("Header") Then
                @RenderSection("Header")
            Else
                @<h1>@ViewData("Title")</h1>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            End If
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required:=False)
</body>
```

***Grower/Index.vbhtml***

```
    @Code
      ViewData("Title") = "Select a Grower/Branch"
    End Code

    @section scripts
      <script type="text/javascript">

      function SuperViewModel() {

        //====== GrowerInfo =======
        var self = this;
        self.GrowerName = ko.observable();
        self.GrowerCompany = ko.observable();
        self.GrowerAddress = ko.observable();
        self.ShowGrowerCompany = ko.observable();
        self.GrowerID = ko.observable();

        self.updateGrowerInfo = function () {
          $.getJSON("GetGrower", function (allData) {
          self.GrowerName(allData.Name);
          self.GrowerCompany(allData.CompanyName);
          self.GrowerAddress(allData.Address);
          self.ShowGrowerCompany(allData.ShowCompany);
          self.GrowerID(allData.ID);
         });
        };

        //Load initial state from server and populate viewmodel
        self.updateGrowerInfo();
        //========= End GrowerInfo ==========

         if ($("#hfFlag").val() == "1") {
          //========= BranchInfo ==========
          self.BranchName = ko.observable();
          self.Company = ko.observable();
          self.Address = ko.observable();
          self.ID = ko.observable();

          //Load initial state from server and populate viewmodel
          self.updateBranchInfo = function () {
           $.getJSON("GetBranch", function (allData) {
            self.BranchName(allData.Name);
            self.Company(allData.CompanyName);
            self.Address(allData.Address);
            self.ID(allData.ID);
          });
        };

        self.updateBranchInfo();
        //=========== End BranchInfo ==============
      }


      //=============== GrowerList ===============
      var MyGrower = function (data) {
       this.growerId = ko.observable(data.GrowerId);
       this.growerName = ko.observable(data.GrowerName);
     };

      self.growers = ko.observableArray([]);

      self.updateGrowers = function () {
        //refresh listview
        $("#ulGrowerList").listview();
        $("#ulGrowerList").listview("refresh");

      $.getJSON("GetGrowers", function (allData) {
        var mappedGrowers = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new MyGrower(item) });
        self.growers(mappedGrowers);


        });
      };

      self.setSelectedClassToGrowerList = function (item, event) {

        $(ulGrowerList).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('highlight');
        $(ulGrowerList).closest('ul').find('.selected').remove();

        $(event.target).toggleClass("highlight");
        if ($(event.target).hasClass("highlight")) {
          $(event.target).append("<span class='selected'>Selected</span>");

          replaceByValue('GrowerID', event.target.id);
          postjsonToServerNow("grower");

          //update GrowerInfo 
          $.getJSON("GetGrower", function (allData) {
            self.GrowerName(allData.Name);
            self.GrowerCompany(allData.CompanyName);
            self.GrowerAddress(allData.Address);
            self.ShowGrowerCompany(allData.ShowCompany);
            self.GrowerID(allData.ID);
          });

        } else {
          $(event.target).find(".selected").remove();
        }
      };



      self.setSelectedClassToBranchList = function (item, event) {

        $(ulBranchList).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('highlight');
        $(ulBranchList).closest('ul').find('.selected').remove();

        $(event.target).toggleClass("highlight");

        if ($(event.target).hasClass("highlight")) {
          $(event.target).append("<span class='selected'>Selected</span>");

          replaceByValue('BranchID', event.target.id);
          postjsonToServerNow("branch");
        } else {
          $(event.target).find(".selected").remove();
        }

      };



      //Load initial state from server and populate viewmodel
      self.updateGrowers();

      //============ End GrowerList =============
    }

    //============= End ViewModel Section ====================//


      $(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
        //enable ko
        ko.applyBindings(new SuperViewModel());


        $("#divBranchList").hide();

        //show hide lists
        $("#btnGrower").click(function () {
        $("#divGrowerList").show();
        $("#divBranchList").hide();
       });

       $("#btnBranch").click(function () {
         $("#divBranchList").show();
         $("#divGrowerList").hide();
       });

      });
    </script>
    End Section




    <table class="maintable" id="maintable">
      <tr>
        <td class="left">
          <div id="GrowerInfo">
            <strong>Grower</strong><br />
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="e" id="btnGrower" data-bind="click: updateGrowers">
              <h3>
               <span data-bind="text: GrowerName"></span>
              </h3>
              <span data-bind="text:GrowerCompany, visible: ShowGrowerCompany" class="block"></span><span data-bind="text: GrowerAddress">
              </span>
              <br />
              <span data-bind="text: GrowerID"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
          @If ViewData("IsDealer") Then
            @<div id="BranchInfo">
              <strong>Branch</strong> <a data-role="button" data-theme="e" id="btnBranch">
                <h3>
                  <span data-bind="text: BranchName"></span>
                </h3>
                <span data-bind="text: Company"></span>
                <br />
                <span data-bind="text: Address"></span>
                <br />
                <span data-bind="text: ID"></span></a>
            </div>
          End If
        </td>
        <td class="splitline">
        </td>
        <td class="right">
          <div class="content-right">
            <div id="divGrowerList" style="overflow: auto; height: 450px; padding: 10px;">

            <p>Total growers: <span data-bind="text: growers().length">&nbsp;</span></p>

               <ul data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-bind="foreach: growers" data-role="listview" id="ulGrowerList">
                  <li><a data-bind="click: $parent.setSelectedClassToGrowerList, attr: {id: growerId}"><span data-bind="text: growerName, attr: {id: growerId}, click: $parent.setSelectedClassToGrowerList" /></a></li>
              </ul>

              <textarea name="growers" rows="10" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(growers)"></textarea>

            </div>
            <div id="divBranchList">
              @If ViewData("IsDealer") Then
                @Html.Action("MyBranchList2")
              End If
            </div>
            @If ViewData("IsDealer") Then
              @<input type="hidden" id="hfFlag" value="1" />
            Else
              @<input type="hidden" id="hfFlag" value="0" />
            End If
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your _Layout.vbhtml I cannot say for certain, but since you have the javascript running on every page it could be possible you have your `script` tag on your _Layout.vbhtml

So, move this into your Index.vbhtml, **or** to place it in the `<head>` tag, use a `@RenderSection("Scripts")` in your Layout.vbhtml and in your view use:

```
@Section "Scripts"

@<script>
    // write JS here or reference a file using the src attribute
</script>

End Section
```

This places everything between `@Section "SectionName"` and `End Section` in your Layout.vbhtml in place of `@RenderSection("Scripts")`

**Edit:**

From your comments to one.beat.consumer I think I see your problem. But understand I am still guessing because I haven't seen your code - **a BIG issue, seeing as you failed to mention you were using jQuery Mobile**.

There are major differences between a regular MVC4 web application and a jQuery Mobile application.

One is: with jQM you are always on the same page -- you load pages from the server, via ajax, which are then stripped down to just `<div data-role="page">...</div>`. This explains why if you put scripts for specific pages in their `<head>` section it will be ignored by jQM. The only `<head>` section not ignored is that of the original page loaded **which isn't always your home page**.

Therefore, to load a script for a specific page you cannot put it in the `<head>` element using MVC Sections. You will need to reference the script within your `<div data-role="page">`. *Although if you are caching your pages this will only fire once, and you may need to bind to `pageshow` if you want it to fire again (to refresh the viewmodel, maybe).*

Lastly,

You said you were applying your viewmodel in you `pageinit` handler. This is called whenever a page is fetched from the server and injected into the DOM.

If you want to keep your js out of the view, you can reference a site-wide js file (custom.js) in your _Layout.vbhtml `<head>` and use:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#PageId', function(event) {
    /* do viewmodel stuff here */
});
```

This will run whenever a `<div data-role="page">` with `id="PageId"` is fetched and injected into the DOM. You can use any selector here, so `.require-vm` can be used to fire when a page with `class="require-vm"` is injected.

Comment: My _layout.vbhtml has a @RenderSection("scripts", required:=False) after closing the <div data-role="page"> but within body. I don't use the Scripts section in the index.vbhtml for the javascript since the javascripts don't work if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your Knockout ViewModel in your `_layout` page.

This is fine if you intend to use this view model on all pages, but it sounds like you don't want to. Move it into the specific action view to isolate it.

in your comment above to Sethi, you mentioned the javascripts don't work when you do that... that is likely because of your placement of the script tags in both the layout and views. I would bet you are trying to build the view model before knockout.js is loaded.

Good practice:

In your layout, place your script tags at the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` close tag... the last tag before it closes should be your `RenderSection()` call as you have it setup.

Now anywhere in your views you can define this script section and ensure that it will occur after your framework scripts - ex. jQuery, Knockout, etc.

Also, keep in mind with jQuery it is almost always preferable to use `$.ready()` to ensure that your scripts run only after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: My knockout.js is included in the <head> tag of _layout and is supposed to be available for each page that are using _layout.vbhtml. I am using $(document).bind('pageinit', function () { per jQuery Mobile recommendation (http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) and doing ko.applyBindings inside that. Don't know if that is the problem and it thinks pageinit as a global initialization of page and so ko models are loading with all views? Created "scripts" section and moving the jscript inside that view didn't help. Please advise.

Comment: Also, to clarify, the knockout viewmodel is in the specific view and not in _layout. I've moved it to the "scripts" section and the javascript seems to break (hiding one div by doing $("divID").hide() inside $(document).bind('pageinit', function () {, but the div shows, moving js out of the section "scripts" works). All functions calls defined in the knockout viewmodel are still executing per Firebug with each view navigation(sigh!).

Comment: Please note that, if I move the ko viewmodel into the "script" section (of the specific view), it does not load at all until I refresh the page! No clue what is happening.

Comment: Added _Layout.vbhtml and Grower/Index.vbhtml markups to my original message.